# How to use a number in the first line of a .txt file to determine the number of words to be printed?

Tags: python, readline, readlines

I have this:

```
from random_word import RandomWords
import time

h = open('/home/rodrigo/Documents/num.txt', 'r')
content = h.readline()

print (content)


a = 0
for line in content:
    for i in line:
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            a += int(i)

r = RandomWords()
key = r.get_random_words()
time.sleep(3)
keys = key[:a]
time.sleep(1)
for key in keys:
    print(key)
```

I'm trying to read and use the number on the first line of a .txt file.
In the .txt file I have just typed the number:

> 50

However, this code reads only the first digit of the number fifty and the result is that the function `print(key)` prints only 5 words (it should print 50 words).

If I change the .txt file to the number: 55
The `print(key)` prints 10 words and not 55 words.
(the function is adding the digits/numeric units of the .txt file)

Can anybody help? How to print an amount of words exactly equal to the number typed in the .txt file?

Comment: i think you wanted to write `content = h.readline`**s**`()`, otherwise, you wouldnt use `for line in content:`, am i correct?

Comment: @alexzander , previously I also tried with readlines(), but it didn't work. I made it work with one of the answers here, I just needed to replace the entire loop with 'a = int (content)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads both digits. But it reads it to a string `"50"`. You then iterate over the digits, convert them to `int`s and add them up, i.e. `int("5") + int("0")`. Which gives you `5` (obviously).

So just replace your whole loop with

```
a = int(content)
```

if you want to check that file only has digits:

```
try:
    a = int(content)
except ValueError:
    print("The content is not intiger")
```

Answer (score 0):

`content` is a string, you are iterating through characters in the string in your first `for` loop (and iterating over the single character string `line` once with your nested `for` loop).

If you only need the one line, replacing your first `for` loop with this should work:

```
 if content.isdigit() == True:
    a += int(content)
```

if you need multiple lines and to add them seperately, add each line to a list like this:

```
from random_word import RandomWords
import time

h = open('/home/rodrigo/Documents/num.txt', 'r')
content = []
line = h.readline()
while line:
    content.append(line)
    line = h.readline()
print (content)


a = 0
for line in content:  # You only need one for loop.
    if line.isdigit() == True:
        a += int(i)

r = RandomWords()
key = r.get_random_words()
time.sleep(3)
keys = key[:a]
time.sleep(1)
for key in keys:
    print(key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and for answering the question!